# Why is mybatis not mapping to my xml file in spring-boot java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

```
      mybatis always doesn't map to my xml file. The BIGINT error is not found, but the mybatis plug-in recognizes it and locates it. Have checked all corresponding class names are OK, looking forward to your answer.Have a nice day.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytSux.png)
This is the error reported
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw9dZ.png)
This is the compiled file directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dS3s.png)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: BIGINT

Comment: The error says `BIGINT` is specified in a wrong place (e.g. `javaType`, `resultType`, etc.). If you still need help, you should improve your question. You should use text instead of images. And check 'preview' before submit.  Including the entire `RoleMapper.xml` might help.